# JQuery: How to get attribute from an object

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a problem getting the innerHTML from an object. At the moment I have this code:

```
console.log( $(myString).find("#" + someID).prevObject );
```

- myString is a string variable of HTML code
- someID is the current ID of the HTML tag to get. In this example, it gets a `<li>` element from the string with the matching ID.

This outputs the following in the console:

[image: Screenshot]

I am just struggling to work out how to get the `innerHTML` attribute from this log.

Cheers

Comment: This is a *fundamentally* different question than it was originally. It's better, when that happens, to post a separate question. Your original question was "how do I get the HTML of an element," which has been answered.

Comment: An observation and a question: You're using `id` values that start with digits (e.g., `id="0"`, `id="1"`, etc.). While that's valid in HTML5, it is **not** valid in CSS or earlier versions of HTML5. Since jQuery uses CSS-style selectors for elements, I'd strongly recommend not doing it (prefix them with an "x" or something). Question: What is `parentId`? Does it relate in some way to the `id` values you're assigning to the `li` elements?

Comment: And finally: The answer here is basically that you shouldn't build up the string. Build up an object graph instead (a bunch of disconnected DOM elements), then when you're done, add the root of that disconnected bunch to the DOM. That way, you can locate and add to any object within the graph (such as the parent `li` you want to put an `ol` in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the HTML of an element via the jQuery [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) function. So assuming the element with the ID really exists:

```
console.log( $(myString).find("#" + someID).html() );
```

That will give you what you said you wanted: The HTML of the `li` with that `id`. Note that I removed the `prevObject`. Two reasons for that:

1. You said you wanted the HTML of the `li` with that `id`. If you do, you don't want `prevObject`.
2. `prevObject` is an **undocumented** aspect of jQuery. It can change meaning, change name, or go away entirely from one dot release to the next. (But mostly point #1.)

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for your previous comments. The problem is, the HTML is not in the DOM, it is just a string. Is there a way to get the closing tag from a string?

Comment: @Patrick: *"The problem is, the HTML is not in the DOM"* That's okay, `$(myString)` turns it into a disconnected set of DOM elements, and `html` will return the HTML of the relevant element. *"Is there a way to get the closing tag from a string?"* I'm not following, what are you looking to get?

Answer (score 2):

You should get the html element from the jquery object like this:

```
console.log( $(myString).find("#" + someID).prevObject[0].innerHTML );
```

or you can access jquerys version of innerHTML

```
console.log( $(myString).find("#" + someID).prevObject.html() );
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - `// Add the old object onto the stack (as a reference)
  ret.prevObject = this;` prevObject is used behind the scenes in jQuery's function chaining.

Comment: @Patrick: I **strongly** recommend not using undocumented features of jQuery. `prevObject` is not documented. Moreover, I fail to see how this gets you what you want. Specifically, it **doesn't** get you the HTML of the `li` with the given ID. Removing the `prevObject` from it does.

Comment: That would be one of those things where a new version changes their chaining technique and you have no clue why your code broke when using the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the element you just need to use html().

```
$('div.demo-container').html();
```

See here for more information:-

http://api.jquery.com/html/